# Распознавание свиста

Tags: java, c++, распознавание

Недавно узнал о приложениях для android, с помощью которых можно найти телефон свистом. Ты свистишь, а телефон начинает пищать.
[Одно из таких приложений.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.appache.findphonebywhistle)
Как реализовать распознавание свиста на языке Java или C++ на компьютере(если это вообще возможно)? Хотелось бы почитать какие-нибудь статьи на эту тему, а сам я ничего не нашел.

Comment: Мастера художественного свиста :) микрофон надо будет включенным держать, и анализировать поток с него, сожрет всю батарейка наверняка. Тестовый свист сравнивать :) сперва хозяин эталонно должен чего то насвистеть :))

Comment: @NewView ,Ну у меня пк стационарный, так что батарейка - не проблема. А на тему "эталонно насвистеть", приложение, на которое я ссылку скинул, и без этого отлично работает, и если кто-то и насвистывал, то только разработчик.

Comment: Значит у вас этот этап художественного свиста впереди :) а стационарный компьютер тоже теряется? может проще проследить от розетки по шнуру питания, вместо свиста? :)

Comment: @NewView ,на компе мне только распознать надо. А там уже придумаю что с ним делать.

Comment: фурье преобразование и вперед